# How to run PROC LOGISTIC on all variables in your dataset in SAS?

Tags: sas, logistic-regression

I have a dataset with 300+ variables and I want to perform stepwise selection in PROC LOGISTIC (I understand stepwise selection is a bad idea here but it's not up to me) on all these variables - some of which are numeric and some of which are categorical.

Without typing the name of each of the 300+ variables, how do I write the model statement so that the model is all variables in my data set except for my response variable? How do I write the class statement so that it knows to treat all the categorical variables as categorical?

Comment: It may be helpful if you could mock up an example with 5 or 10 variables and 10 or 20 observations that looks sort-of like your data, and if you are able to, the PROC LOGISTIC that most closely approximates what you think you would want to run (hand coded).

Comment: write in your model step `model dependent_variable = var1 -- var300;` and then specify in a `class` statement above it the class variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can quickly grab all the headings of your dataset to copy and paste with this:

```
proc contents data = X short;
run;
```

This will generate a list that you can copy and paste into your proc logistic statement.

Assuming your class variables are **character** based you can do the following:

```
proc contents data = X out=test;
run;

data test; set test; 
if TYPE=2;
run

proc transpose data=test out=test2;
var name;
id name;
run;

proc contents data = test2 short;
run;
```